# Is using "new" in the constructor always bad?

Tags: unit-testing, constructors

I have read that using "new" in a constructor (for any other objects than simple value ones) is bad practice as it makes unit testing impossible (as then those collaborators needs to be created too and cannot be mocked).
As I am not really experienced in unit testing, I am trying to gather some rules that I will learn first. 
Also, is this is a rule that is generally valid, regardless of the language used?

Comment: It doesn't make testing impossible. It does make maintaining and testing your code harder, though. Have a read of [new is glue](https://ardalis.com/new-is-glue) for example.

Comment: @DavidArno So if my constructor of class B creates classes C,D,E, wouldn't I need to create them? And thus, there is no isolation of the unit.

Comment: Class B shouldn't create classes C,D,E; they should be injected. Keep things loosely coupled.

Comment: Are C, D and E inner classes? I mean if they were only supposed to be consumed by A's instance, then why not? They would be considered *implementation details*

Comment: "always" is always incorrect.  :)  There are best practices, but exceptions abound.

Comment: @Laiv, good point. There are of course exceptions where the class is an immutable value object, an implementation detail etc where they are supposed to be tightly coupled. As a general rule though, `new` leads to unwanted coupling.

Comment: @DavidArno. I agreed. Just wanted to point to the fact that there are exceptional cases. The answers below are too categoric

Comment: What language is this? `new` means different things in different languages.

Comment: Depends what you're `new`ing. If it's some external thing like a database accessor then yes. If it's a HashMap then no.

Comment: This question depends a bit on the language, doesn't it? Not all languages even have a `new` keyword. What languages are you asking about?

Comment: Silly rule.  Failing to use dependency injection when you should has *very little* to do with the "new" keyword.  Instead of saying that "using new is a problem if you use it to break dependency inversion", just say "don't break dependency inversion".

Comment: Using new in the constructor is a must if you are implementing the PIMPL idiom in C++.

Comment: @Eric `std::make_unique` says otherwise.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are always exceptions, and I take issue with the 'always' in the title, but yes, this *guideline* is generally valid, and also applies outside of the constructor as well.

Using new in a constructor violates the D in SOLID (dependency inversion principle). It makes your code hard to test because unit testing is all about isolation; it is hard to isolate class if it has concrete references.

It is not just about unit testing though. What if I want to point a repository to two different databases at once? The ability to pass in my own context allows me to instantiate two different repositories pointing to different locations.

Not using new in the constructor makes your code more flexible.  This also applies to languages that may use constructs other than `new` for object initialization.

However, clearly, you need to use good judgment. There are plenty of times when  it is fine to use `new`, or where it would be better not to, but you will not have negative consequences. At some point somewhere, `new` has to be called. Just be very careful about calling `new` inside a class that a lot of other classes depend on.

Doing something such as initializing an empty private collection in your constructor is fine, and injecting it would be absurd.

#### The more references a class has to it, the more careful you should be not to call `new` from within it.

Comment: I really don't see any value in this rule. There are rules and guidelines on how to avoid tight coupling in code. This rule seems to deal with the exact same issue, except that it's incredibly too restrictive while not giving us any additional value. So what's the point? Why would creating a dummy header object for my LinkedList implementation instead of dealing with all those special cases that come from having `head = null` in any way improve the code? Why would leaving included collections as null and creating them on demand be better than doing so in the constructor?

Comment: @Voo You have a web application that deals with customers in different regions, normally these regions don't interact so they have different DBs with identical schemas. Your boss wants you to write a command line app to compare cutomer attributes between the regions. This is trivial with DI repositories, and a fair amount of work without DI.

Comment: You're missing the point. Yes a persistence module is absolutely something a higher level module should not depend upon. But "never use new" does **not** follow from "some things should be injected and not directly coupled". If you take your trusty copy of Agile Software Development you'll see that Martin is generally talking about modules not single classes: "The
high level modules deal with the high level policies of the application. These policies generally care little about the details that implement them."

Comment: So the point is that you should avoid dependencies between modules - *particularly* between modules of different abstraction levels. But a module can be more than a single class and there's simply no point erecting interfaces between tightly coupled code of the same abstraction layer. In a well designed application that follows SOLID principles not every single class should implement an interface and not every constructor should always only take interfaces as parameters.

Comment: Or to avoid the rather abstract LinkedList example, let's go with your ORM idea: It makes great sense to introduce an abstraction between your domain model and your repositories. Those two things are clearly separate modules that work on very different abstraction layers. On the other hand there is very little gained from separating your technology specific repositories from the technology specific context. Those things are by necessity tightly coupled and you'll never want to replace just one - for testing you'll simply replace the whole module.

Comment: @Voo The principle of inverting dependency applies to domain objects. Internal implementation objects, such as a header node, are not domain objects. (One could consider the internal structure of a list to be a domain, and may be complex enough to warrant such an analysis, but in general would not be.) So while this answer says it violates the D in SOLID, it only does so for relationships that dependency inversion could ever apply to.

Comment: @corsiKa I think we're agreeing with each other (although if we're talking DDD I'd say inverting dependencies also has value for infrastructure or application layers). There is lots of value in separating different modules from each other, but "using new in a constructor violates SOLID" is waaayy too zealous. There are very many use cases where having `new` is perfectly fine and we have much better rules to decide when we want dependency inversion than this one here.

Comment: I hope my answer was not taken as NEVER EVER NEVER use `new`, as I generally dislike that kind of absolutist thinking. In a top level class, one which nothing is dependent on, can get away with using `new`. Plenty of other times, it would be better not to, but nothing bad is going to happen because you newed in a constructor. OF COURSE *you have to use your judgment*

Comment: I downvoted because it's a lot of buzzword soup and not much discussion about practical considerations. There's something about a repo to two DBs, but honestly, that's not a real world example.

Comment: What a load of bollocks. Do you actually understand what you wrote?

Comment: @jpmc26, BJoBnh Without going into if I condone this answer or not, the point is expressed very clearly. If you think "dependency inversion principal", "concrete reference" or "object initialization" are just buzzwords, then actually you just don't know what they mean. Thats not the answer's fault.

Comment: Someone *has* to invoke `new` eventually. You can wrap as many layers of indirection around the instantiation, there will be code doing it and according to your “generally valid” rule, this code must be bad code then. Bad code wrapped into layers of indirections…

Comment: @Holger Of course someone has to new eventually. It is best if that someone is your IoC container, or your entry function (`Main`). Of course, there are many instances where newing in other places are perfectly fine. However, if one must err, it is better to err on the side of avoiding newing in the constructors.

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't know how you could say working with multiple dbs is not a real world example. Have you not worked somewhere with a test environment?

Comment: It's not even slightly a violation of the dependency inversion principle. SOLID is probably the most misunderstood thing on SoftwareEng. I wish the whole thing would just go away tbh.

Comment: What about a concrete factory that creates a single object in its constructor, pokes this object a bit and then just shares it with all the consumers? I personally would not refactor this.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Actually I'm rather curious how you'd do your whole "same repo class using different contexts" with DI. I had to do exactly the same thing and the way I see it you actually want to explicitly initialize the contexts since there is business logic involved deciding which DBs/servers you need. That's pretty much the exact opposite of how constructor injection and IoC works - you *don't* want to abstract all those details away.

Comment: (I mean for testability you'll still want to separate the creation of the context from the deciding what DB you need. But after that you will have to pass your context somehow to the repository. Or you start playing around with child containers, context local variables and other things - certainly an option, but far from the usual use case for IoC and DI)

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer O_o Obviously I have, but that's a *config* change to put in a different DB host name and credentials. It does *not* require a code change. Because the test and development environments match prod (at least closely enough that code changes aren't required).

Answer (score 52):

While I'm in favor of using the constructor to merely initialize the new instance rather than to create multiple other objects, helper objects are ok, and you have to use your judgement as to whether something is such an internal helper or not.

If the class represents a collection, then it may have an internal helper array or list or hashset.  It would use `new` to create these helpers and it would be considered quite normal.  Such class will not offer injection to use different internal helpers, and has no reason to as these are hidden from the consuming client.  In this case, you want to test the object's public methods, which might go to accumulating, removing, and replacing elements in the collection.

---

In some sense, the class construct of a programming language is a mechanism for creating higher level abstractions, and we create such abstractions to bridge the gap between the problem domain and programming language primitives.  However, the class mechanism is just a tool; it varies by programming language, and, some domain abstractions, in some languages, simply require multiple objects at the level of the programming language.

---

In summary, you have to use some judgement whether the abstraction simply requires one or more internal/helper objects, while still being seen by the caller as a single abstraction, or, whether the other objects would be better exposed to the caller to create for control of dependencies, which would be suggested, for example, when the caller sees these other objects in using the class.

Comment: +1. This is exactly right. You have to identify what the class' intended behavior, and that determines which implementation details need to be exposed and which don't. There's a sort of subtle intuition game you have to play with determining what the class' "responsibility" is, too.

Answer (score 29):

Not all collaborators are interesting enough to unit-test separately, you could (indirectly) test them through the hosting/instantiating class. 
This may not align with some people's idea of needing to test each class, each public method etc. especially when doing test after. 
When using TDD you may refactor out this 'collaborator' extracting out a class where it's already fully under test from your test first process.

Comment: `Not all collaborators are interesting enough to unit-test separately` end of story :-) , This case is possible and nobody dared to mention. @Joppe I encourage you to elaborate the answer a little bit. For example, you could add some examples of classes that are mere implementation details (not suitable for replacement) and how they can be extracted latter if we deem it necessary.

Comment: @Laiv domain models are typically concrete, non-abstract, you don't go about injecting nested objects there. Simple value object/complex object having otherwise no logic are also a candidate.

Comment: +1, absolutely. If a language is set up so that you *have* to call `new File()` to do anything file-related, there's no sense in forbidding that call. What are you going to do, write regression tests against the stdlib's `File` module? Not likely. On the other hand, calling `new` on a *self-invented* class is more dubious.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Good luck unit testing _anything_ which directly calls `new File()`, though.

Comment: That is a *guesswork*. We can find cases where it does not make sense, cases where it's not useful and cases where it make sense and it's useful. It's a matter of needs and preferences.

Comment: This is the best answer here by far.

Answer (score 15):

> As I am not really experienced in unit testing, I am trying to gather some rules that I will learn first.

Be careful learning "rules" for problems you've never encountered. If you come across some "rule" or "best practice", I would suggest finding a simple toy example of where this rule is "supposed" to be used, and trying to solve that problem *yourself*, ignoring what the "rule" says.

In this case, you could try to come up with 2 or 3 simple classes and some behaviours they should implement. Implement the classes in whatever way feels natural and write a unit test for each behaviour. Make a list of any problems you encountered, e.g. if you started off with things working one way, then had to go back and change it later; if you got confused about how things are supposed to fit together; if you got annoyed at writing boilerplate; etc.

*Then* try solving the same problem by following the "rule". Again, make a list of problems you encountered. Compare the lists, and think about which situations might be better when following the rule, and which might not.

---

As for your actual question, I tend to favour a [ports and adapters](http://www.dossier-andreas.net/software_architecture/ports_and_adapters.html) approach, where we make a distinction between "core logic" and "services" (this is similar to distinguishing between pure functions and effectful procedures).

Core logic is all about calculating things "inside" the application, based on the problem domain. It might contain classes like `User`, `Document`, `Order`, `Invoice`, etc. It's fine to have core classes call `new` for other core classes, since they're "internal" implementation details. For example, creating an `Order` might also create an `Invoice` and a `Document` detailing what was ordered. There's no need to mock these during tests, because these are the actual things we want to test!

The ports and adapters are how the core logic interacts with the outside world. This is where things like `Database`, `ConfigFile`, `EmailSender`, etc. live. These are the things which make testing hard, so it's advisable to create these *outside* the core logic, and pass them in as needed (either with dependency injection, or as method arguments, etc.).

This way, the core logic (which is the application-specific part, where the important business logic lives, and is subject to the most churn) can be tested on its own, without having to care about databases, files, emails, etc. We can just pass in some example values and check that we get the right output values.

The ports and adapters can be tested separately, using mocks for the database, filesystem, etc. without having to care about the business logic. We can just pass in some example values and make sure they're being stored/read/sent/etc. appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

Allow me to answer the question, gathering what I consider to be the key points here. I will quote some user for brevity.

> There are always exceptions, but yes, this rule is generally valid,
>   and also applies outside of the constructor as well.
>
> Using new in a constructor violates the **[D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)** in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) (dependency
>   inversion principal). It makes your code hard to test because unit
>   testing is all about isolation; it is hard to isolate class if it has
>   concrete references.
>
> *-TheCatWhisperer-*

Yes, using `new` inside constructors often leads to design flaws (for instance tight-coupling) which makes our design rigid. **Hard to test** yes, but not impossible. The property in play here is **resilience** (tolerance to changes)<sup>1</sup>.

Nevertheless, the above quote is not always true. In some cases, there could be *classes* that are meant to be *tightly coupled*. David Arno has commented a couple.

> There are of course exceptions where the **class is an immutable value**
>   object, **an implementation detail**, etc. **Where they are supposed to be tightly coupled**.
>
> *-David Arno-*

Exactly. Some *classes* (for example inner-classes) could be mere implementation details of the main class. These are meant to be tested alongside with the main class, and they are not necessarily replaceable or extendable.

Moreover, if our [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) cult makes us extract these *classes*, we could be violating another good principle. The so-called [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Which, on the other hand, I find it to be really important from the design point of view.

So the likely answer, as usual, is **depends**. **Using `new` inside constructors can be a bad practice. But not systematically always.**

So, it takes us to evaluate whether the classes are *implementation details* (most of the cases they won't) of the main class. If they are, leave them alone. If they aren't, consider techniques like [Composition Root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6277771/5934037) or [Dependency Injection by IoC Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/871405/5934037).

---

<sup>1: the main goal of SOLID is not to make our code more testable. It's to make our code more tolerant to changes. More flexible and in consequence, easier to test</sup>

<sup>***Note:*** David Arno, TheWhisperCat, I hope you don't mind I quoted you.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

As a simple example, consider the following pseudocode

```
class Foo {
  private:
     class Bar {}
     class Baz inherits Bar {}
     Bar myBar
  public:
     Foo(bool useBaz) { if (useBaz) myBar = new Baz else myBar = new Bar; }
}
```

Since the `new` is a pure implementation detail of `Foo`, and both `Foo::Bar` and `Foo::Baz` are part of `Foo`, when unit testing of `Foo` there is no point in mocking parts of `Foo`. You only mock the parts **outside** `Foo` when unit-testing `Foo`.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, using 'new' in your application root classes is a code smell.  It means you are locking the class into using a specific implementation, and will not be able to substitute another.  Always opt for injecting the dependency into the constructor.  That way not only will you be able to easily inject mocked dependencies during testing, but it will make your application much more flexible by allowing you to quickly substitute different implementations if needed.

EDIT:
For downvoters - here's a link to a software development book flagging 'new' as a possible code smell: https://books.google.com/books?id=18SuDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT169&dq=new%20keyword%20code%20smell&pg=PT169#v=onepage&q=new%20keyword%20code%20smell&f=false

Comment: I am sorry, what does a "non-root" clause mean? Still learning

Comment: `Yes, using 'new' in your non-root classes is a code smell. It means you are locking the class into using a specific implementation, and will not be able to substitute another.` Why is this a problem? Not every single dependency in a dependency tree should be open to replacement

Comment: Also, is there something like a list of language agnostic code smells I could study? I have also heard about not using static calls

Comment: Likewise, what if you want to have default implementations while still allowing for injection?  Would that not also be implementable via 'new' in the constructor without being a code smell?

Comment: @Paul: Having a  default implementation means that you take a tightly-bound reference to the concrete class specified as the default.  That doesn't make it a so-called "code smell," though.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca: I would be cautious about using the words "code smell" in any context.  It's kinda like saying "republican" or "democrat;" what do those words even mean?  As soon as you give something a label like that, you stop thinking about the real issues, and learning stops.

Comment: "More flexible" is not automatically "better".

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, then lets call it "bad practices?" I mean, I would love to learn more when it comes to writing a good, testable code. But books are not really specific in this

Comment: @EzoelaVacca I meant application root.  It's the place in your application where you new-up all your classes, and inject them as dependencies.  A related search term would be IoC container.  I highly recommend the following book - the first few chapters are language agnostic: "Dependency Injection in .NET": https://www.amazon.com/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501

Comment: @EzoelaVacca Here's an example from literature where newing up objects in constructor is referred to as a code smell: https://books.google.com/books?id=18SuDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT169&lpg=PT169&dq=new+keyword+code+smell&source=bl&ots=CvDJ8jRJ1k&sig=0JXsyCCh3ZKfqeWIZsqyTo3rpuk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLqMeSn4XZAhUNd98KHbMPDHYQ6AEISDAE#v=onepage&q=new%20keyword%20code%20smell&f=false

Comment: @EzoelaVacca: Using the `new` keyword is not a bad practice, and never was.  It's *how* you use the tool that matters.  You don't use a sledgehammer, for example, where a ball peen hammer will suffice.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right, of course I meant in this situation

Comment: @EzoelaVacca: What situation would that be?  You haven't provided any detail in your question about your specific situation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Using in constructors and unit testing. As most here agree, and also books, it is generally considered not a good thing.