# Is using the copy constructor in an object's construction is bad?

Tags: java, constructors, defensive-programming

I was reading [this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365119/is-using-new-in-the-constructor-always-bad) about using the `new` keyword in the constructor, and I was wondering if it applies to copy constructors for collections.

Suppose I have a `Book` class and a collection to store a `set` of `authors`.

```
class Book {

    private String title;
    private Set<Author> authorsSet;

    Book (title, authors){
        this.title = title
        this.authorsSet = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Author>(authors)) 
    }
}
```

It's a good idea to make a defensive copy so that client code cannot change the internals of `authorsSet`.

Is calling `this.authorsSet = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Author>(authors))` a violation of the guideline that a constructor shouldn't call the `new` keyword? If so, how do we make a defensive copy without the `new` keyword?

Comment: Specifically the [highest voted answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/365123/118878) directly addresses your question.

Comment: "Doing something such as initializing an empty private collection in your constructor is fine, and injecting it would be absurd"

Comment: @Ewan - It's not an empty private collection, it's actually copying items from one `set` to another. The constructor is actually doing work with the `set`.

Comment: It's not doing anything except getting your object into a valid initial state - it's not work.

Comment: Sveta, no offense, but you are often asking question of the form "here is a braindead cargo cult rule, should I follow it or should I start thinking by myself", and the answer you got in the past from different people was always "start thinking by yourself". Robert Harvey describes this as "there is no best practice (=braindead rule), only solutions to requirements". So don't expect anything different this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If in a constructor of class A another object of class B is constructed by `new`, then A has a hard dependency on B, which makes it impossible to test A isolated from B, which can be resolved by injecting a B instance into A through a constructor parameter of some interface type which B implements. But that is only a necessary

- if you actually **want or need to unit test A isolated from B**.

In the shown case, that would mean to unit test `Book` isolated from the class `HashSet` - which is probably not what you want or need. Collection classes like `HashSet` can be treated as elements of your framework or programming languages (actually, in some languages like Perl or Python they *are* elements of the language). They are lightweight, fast, can be assumed to be bugfree for all practical purposes, and often most your code depends on them anyway. So it typically makes no sense to break a dependency on them.